# Is comment metadata included in the export file?

Tags: comments, export

If I would export a WordPress database, posts and comments etc. are saved to an XML file.
Would comment metadata be included in this XML file?

I.e. the table `wp_commentmeta`, mentioned here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_commentmeta.

Here:
[The WordPress eXtended Rss (WXR) Export/Import, XML Document Format Decoded and Explained](http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/the-wordpress-extended-rss-wxr-exportimport-xml-document-format-decoded-and-explained/)
I found some info on the export file format, and the columns in `wp_comments` are mentioned, but there's no mentioning of any columns in `wp_commentmeta`.

**Edit:** Background: I'm planning to write a new commenting system for WordPress, and I'd like to be able to import/export comment data between various blog platforms. (E.g. Blogger and others.) And I think I need to use the comment metadata table. **/Edit**

Kind regards, Magnus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My latest export from my blog (WP 3.3.1) now has the commentmeta in the XML. It's in this format:

```
        <wp:comment>
        <wp:comment_id>...</wp:comment_id>
        ...
        <wp:comment_user_id>0</wp:comment_user_id>
        **<wp:commentmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>name_of_meta</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[value_of_meta]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:commentmeta>**
    </wp:comment>
```

I was looking for information on it while trying to write an exporter from another system. Not much information available online so I tried an export from a well-used blog--it was there!

Comment: Yes, indeed, [here in version 3.3 of export.php it's being exported](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-admin/includes/export.php#L420). It's present in v 3.2 but not in 3.1 (which is the version Jan Fabry's answer conserns).   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the export code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/includes/export.php#L393), it seems comments don't include comment meta information. The lines above it explicitly include post metadata, but I don't see a query for comment metadata.

Comment: Thanks. How sad, now it'll be much more complicated to write a custom discussion plugin that uses comment metadata, and can be exported/imported between different blog platforms. -- Also, how silly, I cannot upvote your answer: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".

Comment: Thanks for the link to `export.php`, I found it very interesting, didn't know where to find the export file format documentation but it's in that file :-)

Comment: Nowadays it's included, from v 3.2 and onwards it seems, [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-admin/includes/export.php#L420).